# How to implement the following formula for derivatives in python?

Tags: python, math, derivative

I'm trying to implement the following formula in python for X and Y points

[image]

I have tried following approach

```
def f(c):
    """This function computes the curvature of the leaf."""
    tt = c
    n = (tt[0]*tt[3] - tt[1]*tt[2])
    d = (tt[0]**2 + tt[1]**2)
    k = n/d
    R = 1/k # Radius of Curvature
    return R
```

There is something incorrect as it is not giving me correct result. I think I'm making some mistake while computing derivatives in first two lines. How can I fix that?

Here are some of the points which are in a data frame:

```
pts = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})


           x            y
    0.089631    97.710199
    0.089831    97.904541
    0.090030    98.099313
    0.090229    98.294513
    0.090428    98.490142
    0.090627    98.686200
    0.090827    98.882687
    0.091026    99.079602
    0.091225    99.276947
    0.091424    99.474720
    0.091623    99.672922
    0.091822    99.871553
    0.092022    100.070613
    0.092221    100.270102
    0.092420    100.470020
    0.092619    100.670366
    0.092818    100.871142
    0.093017    101.072346
    0.093217    101.273979
    0.093416    101.476041
    0.093615    101.678532
    0.093814    101.881451
    0.094013    102.084800
    0.094213    102.288577


pts_x = np.gradient(x_c, t)  # first derivatives
pts_y = np.gradient(y_c, t)
pts_xx = np.gradient(pts_x, t)  # second derivatives
pts_yy = np.gradient(pts_y, t)
```

After getting the derivatives I am putting the derivatives x_prim, x_prim_prim, y_prim, y_prim_prim in another dataframe using the following code:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'x_prim': pts_x, 'y_prim': pts_y, 'x_prim_prim': pts_xx, 'y_prim_prim':pts_yy})
```

after having everything in the data frame I am calling function for each row of the data frame to get curvature at that point using following code:

```
# Getting the curvature at each point
for i in range(len(d)):
    temp = d.iloc[i]
    c_temp = f(temp)
    curv.append(c_temp)
```

Comment: Did you try looking at what you get for pts_x, pts_y, pts_xx and pts_yy and see whether those are being calculated approximately correctly? Also, I don't see anything corresponding to the notion of "absolute value" here... your n could turn out negative.

Comment: @Patrick87 I just checked that that is somewhere it is getting fuzzy. If I compute all the derivatives separately then it should solve the problem. Let me try that.

Comment: Do those primes mean "derivative" to you?

Comment: The root of the sum of squares is positive-definite, so no concerns about complex values here.

Comment: @duffymo yes. pts_x is first derivative and pts_xx is second derivative.

Comment: Is there a summation in here somewhere?  Either you've left off a summation to give you a constant value k OR k is really a function.  Which is it?  What are you expecting?  Are you supposed to be multiplying values at a point?  Or is that a dot product of two vectors that evaluates to a scalar?  You need to understand the formula before you can code it.  I can't say that I do from what you've posted.

Comment: @duffymo It is formula for the curvature that I found on https://www.math24.net/curvature-plane-curves/  link in the section for getting the curvature when the coordinates x(t) and y(t) of a curve are given parametrically.

Comment: The curvature varies at every point.  The key bit from the np.gradient documentation: "The returned gradient hence has the same shape as the input array."  Those are arrays.  When you multiply one array by another, what do you expect to get?

Comment: I need to get |k| which is shown on the blog for which I shared link with you.

Comment: Got it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature.  It's the curvature of a curve defined by two vectors of points x and y.  I'd assume that x is in sorted order.  There is a different value of k at each point x of the curve.  I'd recommend that you reconsider your programming.  It's not correct.

Comment: @duffymo Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191933/discussion-between-upriser-and-duffymo).

Comment: No chat for me.  Sorry.

Comment: @duffymo I'll update you when I implement this.

Comment: Please *always* use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Only use a version specific tag if you think it's important.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment, please show how you call your function, especially showing the value of the `pts` array. Without that, we are just guessing about your problem.

Comment: Your edit is not sufficient to clarify just what `pts` is. Are the numbers in the first column starting with `450` part of the `pts` array? Is it an array or a dataset? If an array, what is its shape? And so on--the details matter for a problem like this. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryDaulton the numbers from the 450 in the first column are just indices. I'll edit my question sorry for that.

Comment: Doesn't your data allow for the simplified formula in case of the [curvature of the graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_the_graph_of_a_function)? You might also think about using `scipy.interpolate.splev` as this provides the possibility to get derivatives. In any case it does not make sense to get the curvature on edge points...or it is at least questionable.

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify exactly what the structure of the parameter `pts` is. But it seems that it is a two-dimensional array where each row has two values `x` and `y` and the rows are the points in your curve. That itself is problematic, since [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) is not quite clear on what exactly is returned in such a case.

But you clearly are not getting the derivatives of `x` or `y`. If you supply only one array to `np.gradient` then numpy assumes that the points are evenly spaced with a distance of one. But that is probably not the case. The meaning of `x'` in your formula is the derivative of `x` *with respect to `t`*, the parameter variable for the curve (which is separate from the parameters to the computer functions). But you never supply the values of `t` to numpy. The values of `t` must be the second parameter passed to the `gradient` function.

So to get your derivatives, split the `x`, `y`, and `t` values into separate one-dimensional arrays--lets call them `x` and `y` and `t`. Then get your first and second derivatives with

```
pts_x = np.gradient(x, t)  # first derivatives
pts_y = np.gradient(y, t)
pts_xx = np.gradient(pts_x, t)  # second derivatives
pts_yy = np.gradient(pts_y, t)
```

Then continue from there. You no longer need the `t` values to calculate the curvatures, which is the point of the formula you are using. Note that `gradient` is not really designed to calculate the second derivatives, and it absolutely should not be used to calculate third or higher-order derivatives. More complex formulas are needed for those. Numpy's `gradient` uses "second order accurate central differences" which are pretty good for the first derivative, poor for the second derivative, and worthless for higher-order derivatives.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give example what t array would look like. x and y arrays that I have are floating point values.

Comment: I'm busy right now but will try to respond later. It would help if you show an example of your `pts` data--that would make your code snippet more complete, according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RonyDaulton Hello Rony, should I consider x = t in my case or it is different.

Comment: @Upriser: I do not mean to be rude, but I will not do any more work on your question or my answer until you actually [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What *exactly* is `pts`? Showing a text representation is not enough--show its data structure in Python in executable code. A reduced version is fine if it shows your problem. And just how is your code "not giving me correct result"? What do you get, what do you expect, and how are they different?

Comment: @RonyDaulton I added the approach that I tried, and this is pretty much everything I have. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that x and y are arrays of double values.

The array x is the independent variable; I'd expect it to be sorted into ascending order.  If I evaluate y[i], I expect to get the value of the curve at x[i].

When you call that numpy function you get an array of derivative values that are the same shape as the (x, y) arrays.  If there are n pairs from (x, y), then

```
y'[i] gives the value of the first derivative of y w.r.t. x at x[i]; 

y''[i] gives the value of the second derivative of y w.r.t. x at x[i].
```

The curvature k will also be an array with n points:

```
k[i] = abs(x'[i]*y''[i] -y'[i]*x''[i])/(x'[i]**2 + y'[i]**2)**1.5
```

Think of x and y as both being functions of a parameter t.  x' = dx/dt, etc.   This means curvature k is also a function of that parameter t.

I like to have a well understood closed form solution available when I program a solution.

```
y(x) = sin(x) for 0 <= x <= pi
y'(x) = cos(x)
y''(x) = -sin(x)
k = sin(x)/(1+(cos(x))**2)**1.5
```

Now you have a nice formula for curvature as a function of x.

If you want to parameterize it, use

```
x(t) = pi*t for 0 <= t <= 1
x'(t) = pi
x''(t) = 0
```

See if you can plot those and make your Python solution match it.

Comment: Is this implementation same as you suggested from the wiki blog.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the wiki entry is describing your problem.  Try my idea about implementation and see if your results make more sense.  Do it for a curve that you know the answer to, like y = sin(x) for 0 <= x <= pi.  You can evaluate that analytically and check your programming solution against it.

Comment: I tried for the sin curve but this approach is not giving correct result. I need to go by different approach probably the wiki blog approach as the blog that I found math24.net/curvature-plane-curves I think it is misleading or it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No.  You need to understand the problem.  My source and yours are describing the same problem.  I don't know what "tried" looks like; I don't know what result you got or expected.  I don't think you understand your problem.

Comment: I mean I tried to get the curvature of the sine curve but it is not giving the correct answer I referred another blog which was doing simulation for the curvature of the sine curve and the values are not matching I generated the sine curve with the same parameter as described in blog. I think the dx/dy that I'm taking is making something wierd I need to check documentation again if it is giving dy/dx or dx/dy the order of the parameters x and y.

Comment: The code that you suggested is working. I just tried it. In my code I forgot to consider pi (it's a silly mistake that I made.)